# get dates from database where with special conditions

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i built this fiddle for you:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=35f21ff5601276b4dba0e9250594d101

There is a query, which should get alle timeslots of a day, with the following conditions:

- no timeslots with service 1 or 3 on this day? > Get all timeslots
- is there one or more services with 1 or 3 on this day ? > Get all timeslots before this services

this works fine !
But now I have a new Problem !

- is there a service 0 available, like the fiddle shows, additional get timeslots after this service 0.

the fiddle shows me as result:

```
2021-07-07 14:00:00
```

But I would like to have also

```
2021-07-07 16:00:00
```

because before this slot is a service = 0

Can you help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "*immediately*  before this slot is a service = 0", then try:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `timeslots` ts
WHERE (
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL FROM `timeslots` ts2
            WHERE DATE(ts2.`timeslot`) = DATE(ts.`timeslot`)
            AND TIME(ts2.`timeslot`) <= TIME(ts.`timeslot`)
            AND `service` != 2
        )
    OR
        EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL FROM `timeslots` ts2
            WHERE DATE(ts2.`timeslot`) = DATE(ts.`timeslot`)
            AND DATE_SUB(ts.`timeslot`, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) = ts2.`timeslot`
            AND ts2.`service` = 0
        )    
    )
AND `timeslot` > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY `timeslot`
```

[See db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d219f72f2c8a24bbae18c1a2b3b52888)